# Does timer affect other processes?

Tags: asp.net, timer

I am using timer and thread in class file and then calling this class file in global file. If timer calls then will it affect other processes of the website ???

My code is as below :

```
public void Scheduler_Start()
{
     Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadFunc));
     thread.IsBackground = true;
     thread.Name = "ThreadFunc";
     thread.Start();
}
protected void ThreadFunc()
{
     System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
     t.Interval = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
     t.Enabled = true;
     t.AutoReset = true;
     t.Start();
     t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerWorker);
}
protected void TimerWorker(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
      // Code here...
}
```

Gloabl File :

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Scheduler myScheduler = new Scheduler();
     myScheduler.Scheduler_Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If timer calls then will it affect other processes of the website ???

No, it will not affect other applications and processes. By the way when you wrote this recurring background processing in your web application were you aware of the [`dangers`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx)?

Comment: Nope. I don't know. Let me know if anything can be wrong with this.

Comment: Yes, many things can get wrong with this. Read the article I have linked to in my answer to understand them.

Comment: We are having dedicated server.

Comment: What you should do is perform those background tasks in a separate application such as a Windows Service for example.

Comment: ohk, We are having dedicated server so no prob. But what if it is shared hosting, that time hosting provider wont allow to install windows app. so what should i do to use it in web app only ???

Comment: I think you are not understanding the problem here. The fact that you have a dedicated server won't help you. IIS can bring your application down at any moment.

Comment: Ohk, I got it. Can u suggest me something to do with this code only by which i can prevent problem ??? I dont want to use windows app...

Comment: You should use either a Windows Service or a Console application which could be scheduled to execute at regular intervals using the Windows Scheduler. Do not use background processes in an ASP.NET application.

Comment: but what will you say when the case is of shared hosting. that time they wont allow to access their server.

Comment: Well, that's a serious problem.

Comment: That will depend on many factors. For example if certain CPU or memory thresholds are reached. Or after a certain period of inactivity on the site. I am not saying that you should not do it. I just say that if you do it, you'd better be well familiar with the consequences and take your own risks.

Comment: I am sending email to around 5000 users in background process.

Comment: Alright, I think I already made my point. Now it's up to you to take your risks.